# How to place text from a textbox into a richtextbox vb and add extra text to the RichTextBox

Tags: vba

I want to know how to take the text a user places from a textbox into a RichTextBox. For example:

TextBox = **Waffles**

RichTextBox = These **(Text from TextBox)** are good

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox.Text = "Waffles"
RichTextBox.Text = TextBox.Text & "Text to Add"
```

**EDIT**: Updated with further question from OP in comments.

> How can I add quotation marks to the text?

To print quotation mark in a string you need to enclose them in string delimiter quotes:

```
dim str as String
dim quotedStr as String
str = "My Text"
quotedStr = """ & str & """
```

Or in your case 
RichTextBox.Text = """ & TextBox.Text & """

Comment: alright what if i want it so the text "waffles" is placed as These "waffles" are good. and if place other text from other textboxes on another line when i press a button

Comment: One last thing how can I quote the text from textbox in the richtrxtbox

Comment: Lol sorry for this final thing, how may I make a button to update the richtextbox

Comment: Updated the answer. As for the button: just place a Button control on whatever userform your TextBox and RichTextBox are on, double click it and put the code inside the `_Click()` function that is generated.

Comment: Oh yea and about making each textbox print a new line??

Comment: Google is your friend.